# Spring - separate directory for controllers

Tags: java, spring, controllers

I'm a newbie in Spring and have one question about inserting all controllers in another directory than an executable spring boot file.

[This tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

I have to have **GreetingController.java** and **Application.java** in one directory because if not, then I can't run mvn spring:boot-run

Is there a way to have **Application.java** in */java* directory and all controllers in */java/controllers*? Can I create some config file to inform **Application.java** where all the files are?

Thank you

Comment: I think you're looking for packages in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am little bit confused. But first point - It is good to have all controllers in separate directory, it is best practise, but better is using */rest* directory.
Second point - You have to define application context and enable few things (for example via annotation). Try to look here http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html, here you can see annotations and basic structure.
For you, set this annotations to your Application.java:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
```

More information and where to write it you can find in link what I posted.
If you configure application context and you set EnableAutoconfiguration and ComponentScan, Spring will look up for all annotated components and your controllers (if you annotated you controller class by `@Controller` annotation.